# Getting class of Object Parameter

Tags: java

Is it possible to get the class of an object parameter in a java method?

Example in the code below:

```
public Class<?> getSourceType(Object... value) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(value), classLoader);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error(LogMessages.TARGET_CLASS_WAS_NOT_FOUND, e);
    }

    return clazz;
}
```

If I call getSourceType like below:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Class<?> myClazz = getSourceType(map);
```

I am interested in getting java.util.Map for myClazz. Instead I am getting java.lang.Object. Any idea how I can get the passed parameter class, in this case java.util.Map?

Comment: I don't understand. Why use `Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(value), classLoader);` when you can just do `value.getClass()`? Or am I interpreting your question wrong?

Comment: @user, I tried both value.getClass and the ClassUtils.getUserClass to see if I can get the passed class and not Object so yes value.getClass() is what I used before.

Comment: `value.getClass()` should work return `Map.class`. Are you talking about the inferred type? If so, you can just cast a `Class<Object>` to a `Class<Map>`

Comment: value.getClass() is returning java.lang.Object. I don't know the class of the value to cast it in advance. I need to be able to retrieve the inferred type for any value.

Comment: I think this code should be returning `Object[].class` (which responds `class [Ljava.lang.Object;` to `toString()`). The real `Object.class` would look like call itself `class java.lang.Object`. This is because you're finding the class of `value`, which is `Object...`, i.e. an `Object[]`. Perhaps `value[0].getClass()`? My question is why are you taking the argument as a vararg? There might be no classes to return (`value` is empty) or multiple (`value` has multiple elements).

Comment: First of all, I don't understand why you have variadic arguments `Object... value`. This will return a Class representing an array, right?

Comment: I'd make the method look something like `<T> Class<T> getClass(T value) { return value.class; }`

Comment: This is the use case. I need to have it as a variadic but you have a really good point. I am getting a list back so I am wondering if I can get the inferred object from the variadic variable.